# how to list full url about helm search url in v3.2.1

Tags: kubernetes

When I use this command to search hub's avaliable chart:

```
helm search hub kubernetes-dashboard
```

it only show part of the url like this:

```
[miaoyou@MeowK8SMaster1 ~]$ helm search hub kubernetes-dashboard
URL                                                 CHART VERSION   APP VERSION DESCRIPTION                                   
https://hub.helm.sh/charts/k8s-dashboard/kubern...  2.0.1           2.0.1       General-purpose web UI for Kubernetes clusters
https://hub.helm.sh/charts/banzaicloud-stable/k...  0.9.2           1.10.0      General-purpose web UI for Kubernetes clusters
```

how to show the full url about hub,I could not find name about the hub and did not know how to install it using `helm install` command? copy url from terminal only have part of url.

Comment: helm search -o  < prints output in the specified format, json, yaml, table is by default.

Comment: `[miaoyou@MeowK8SMaster1 ~]$ helm search -o
Error: unknown shorthand flag: 'o' in -o` @abestrad

Comment: `helm search hub -o json`
[{"Name":"stable/hubot","Version":"1.0.1","AppVersion":"3.3.2","Description":"Hubot chatbot for Slack"},{"Name":"stable/eventrouter","Version":"0.3.0","AppVersion":"0.3","Description":"A Helm chart for eventruter (https://github.com/heptiolabs/eventrouter)"} ....

Comment: it works, thank you !@abestrad

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use this command to see full output:

```
[miaoyou@MeowK8SMaster1 ~]$ helm search hub -o json kubernetes-dashboard|jq '.'
[
  {
    "url": "https://hub.helm.sh/charts/k8s-dashboard/kubernetes-dashboard",
    "version": "2.0.1",
    "app_version": "2.0.1",
    "description": "General-purpose web UI for Kubernetes clusters"
  },
  {
    "url": "https://hub.helm.sh/charts/banzaicloud-stable/kubernetes-dashboard",
    "version": "0.9.2",
    "app_version": "1.10.0",
    "description": "General-purpose web UI for Kubernetes clusters"
  }
]
```

if you do not have `jq`, install it use this command in CentOS:

```
sudo yum install jq -y
```

if using another operation system, replace the package manager.

Answer (score 3):

```
helm search hub wordpress --output yaml
```

happy reading

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 1):

```
helm search hub wordpress -o table --max-col-width 120
```